# Looping through list in python to create multiple files

Tags: python

I've been messing around with lists and creating files from a list. The below works fine but I'm sure that there is a better and cleaner way for doing this. I understand the concept of a loop but can't find a specific example which I could remodel to fit what I am doing. Please could someone please point me in the right direction of looping my items list through the f.write code only the once, to generate the files that I'm after.

```
    items = [ "one", "two", "three" ]

    f = open (items[0] + " hello_world.txt", "w")
    f.write("This is my first line of code")
    f.write("\nThis is my second line of code with " + items[0] + " the first item in my list")
    f.write ("\nAnd this is my last line of code")

    f = open (items[1] + " hello_world.txt", "w")
    f.write("This is my first line of code")
    f.write("\nThis is my second line of code with " + items[1] + " the first item in my list")
    f.write ("\nAnd this is my last line of code")

    f = open (items[2] + " hello_world.txt", "w")
    f.write("This is my first line of code")
    f.write("\nThis is my second line of code with " + items[2] + " the first item in my list")
    f.write ("\nAnd this is my last line of code")
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop and a [with](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement like this. The advantage of using `with` statement is that, you dont have to explicitly close the files or worry about the cases where there is an exception.

```
items = ["one", "two", "three"]

for item in items:
    with open("{}hello_world.txt".format(item), "w") as f:
        f.write("This is my first line of code")
        f.write("\nThis is my second line of code with {} the first item in my list".format(item))
        f.write("\nAnd this is my last line of code")
```

Comment: This works just as great as the above answer but perhaps is a little more friendlier on the kinda code that I want to add. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You should use a for loop

```
for item in  [ "one", "two", "three" ]:
    f = open (item + " hello_world.txt", "w")
    f.write("This is my first line of code")
    f.write("\nThis is my second line of code with " + item  + " the first item in my list")
    f.write ("\nAnd this is my last line of code")
    f.close()
```

Comment: @geomiles The `for` statement line should have a `:` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Regular for loop - with some optimizing.

Data:

```
items = ["one", "two", "three" ]
content = "This is the first line of code\nThis is my second line of code with %s the first item in my list\nAnd this is my last line of code"
```

Loop:

```
for item in items:
    with open("%s_hello_world.txt" % item, "w") as f:
        f.write(content % item)
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you very much. I guessed that there would be a for statement in there somewhere but it just a matter of knowing where to put it. Cheers again