# how to open, modify, and save multiple .txt files?

Tags: python, file, pycharm

```
with open('90_out.csv', 'w') as f:
data = open('A:/pycharm/study0722/data/90.txt', 'r')
f.write('year, month, day, tmax, tavg, tmin, rainfall')
f.write('\n')
for line in data:
    tokens = line.split()
    year = int(tokens[0])
    month = int(tokens[1])
    day = int(tokens[2])
    tmax = float(tokens[3])
    tavg = float(tokens[4])
    tmin = float(tokens[5])
    rainfall = float(tokens[10])
    f.write("{:d}, {:d}, {:d}, {:.1f}, {:.1f}, {:.1f}, {:.1f}".format(year, month, day, tmax, tavg, tmin, rainfall))
    f.write('\n')
```

I modified and saved one txt file with the above code. Approximately 50 files should be worked in the same way. but i don't know how to open multiple files and save each other.

*i used pycharm

Comment: What are the names of your files?

Comment: What did you try and why did it fail? If processing of one file works and therefore is _not_ your problem, than do not post this part of the code.

Comment: May I kindly ask what you are trying to do? If I look at your code, source and target files differ only in the separator. Do you want to copy your files while only replacing space-separators by commas?

Comment: this may be a copy paste issue, but the with open has nothing under it's indentation, I believe all lines under must be indented one.

Comment: You hardly need to write 50 identical files, do you? So how do the other 49 differ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904120/looping-through-list-in-python-to-create-multiple-files

Answer (score 0):

You should make a list of all files, lets say `file_list` and use the following code

```
for single_file in file_list:
    with open(single_file, 'w') as f:
        do_something()
```

You should search google, the question has been answered multiple times already

Answer (score 0):

First: If you want to loop over several files, you'll need a list of them. If you don't want to create it manually, you can read a folder, for example. Possibly you want to process all *.txt files in a certain folder:

```
import glob
source_folder = '/wherever/files/may/roam/'

src_list = glob.glob(source_folder + '*.txt')
```

Second: if you want to process two files in each iteration, you can open them in one `with`-block:

```
for src in src_list:
    a = src.rfind('\\')
    b = src.rfind('.')
    tgt = src[a+1: b] + '.csv'
    with open(src, 'r') as sf, open(tgt, 'w') as tf:
        _process_anything_here_
```

Third: if you only want to make a comma-sparated copy of a space-separated file, you could use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table(sf, sep='\s+')
df.to_csv(tf)
```

and in case of the problem is that the source file has no headers, you could just add them when writing the target file:

```
df.to_csv(tf, header=['year, month, day, tmax, tavg, tmin, rainfall'])
```